# CSS Table automatic height with rotated text

Tags: html, css

So I have to make a table on my website. I use a ton of row-span and col-span. In one of the cells I have to rotate the text with 90°. Here is a picture of the chart so far. [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXtaS.png) I can't figure out the code in the CSS to make the cell auto adapt to the height of the vertical text. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: put the code you try before

Comment: .vertikalText{transform: rotate(-90deg);height: auto;} height:auto; doesn't work and neither does height: 100%

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there's a way to do what you want using transforms. You're probably better off altering the `writing-mode` property. It's got [excellent browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-writing-mode) for modern browsers across the board.

> The writing-mode CSS property defines whether lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically and the direction in which blocks progress.

To make it work on your table cell, you'll need to change it to inline block. Here's a short example which hopefully points you the right direction (pun absolutely intended).

```css
td { 
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
}

.vertical {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>horizontal text</td>
    <td class="vertical">long vertical text</td>     
    <td>horizontal text</td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Rotating the text like this works fine, but the cells somewhat break. The cells break with it tough.

Comment: and if you want it upsidedown, just use "transform: rotate(180deg);" and the height still is fine

Answer (score 1):

You can try it:

```js
$(function() {
    var header_height = 0;
    $('table th span').each(function() {
        if ($(this).outerWidth() > header_height) header_height = $(this).outerWidth();
    });

    $('table th').height(header_height);
});
```

```css
table, tr, td, th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

th span {
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  white-space: nowrap; 
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th><span>Shorter Title</span></th>
          <th><span>Much Much Longer Title</span></th>
      </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you, tough i can't use this after all my assignment is to use as little js as possible(and no jquery at all :( )

Comment: If someone want a non-jquery solution that also centers the text vertically, [here is my edit of the answer](https://ghostbin.com/paste/nbozo)